# Should the raycaster always be located in the render() function?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to catch the location of the mouse double-click event and create an object on its place in 3D scene.

As I understood raycaster, located in the render() function updates the location of the mouse continuously. I want it to be done only when the double-click takes place. Does it make sense to put it into the object creation function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it pretty much where you want it. That's especially important if you're scenes are super complex.. you will find you need to restrict when/how often you raycast, and also control what you're raycasting against.. like just raycasting against a subtree of your scene or against a specific array of objects.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too, but in all the examples I saw, the Raycaster is usually in the render() part of the script. Thanks, you clarified it for me :)